# Technical obstacles in making a noiseless thermic motor?

Tags: motors

There seems to be no noiseless thermic motor for cars or motorcycles on the market.

Is there a technical obstacle at making such a product ?

Is there a way to isolate/eliminate noises from the explosion process and from the moving parts ?

Comment: This question is very broad. There are a lot of different components that make noise. Each of these may require different methods of noise suppression if it is even possible. Is there a specific area of the motor that you are asking about?

Comment: You are right, i'll try better on my next question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the nature of what an explosion is, I doubt we can just suppress the sound at it's source. The only way is to use a different motor technology.

However, car manufacturers tend to isolate the motor compartment from the outside with basic noise-suppressing technologies which are for example : covering the compartment with absorbing materials like foams or using bushed fixations ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushing_%28isolator%29)). Most highly priced cars are well isolated, for example I know that you barely hear the sound of the motor in recent BMW cars.

Here is a picture of some bmw compartment. You can see that when the cover is closed, a plastic joint isolates the cover from the chassis.
[image]